# Azure - Não cria as tabelas

Tags: microsoft-azure

Criei um projeto ASP.Net MVC 5, fiz algumas modificações no *login* e na minha maquina ocorre tudo tranquilamente, porém quando envio pro Azure, na hora de criar o usuário ocorre erro. O que consegui perceber é que as tabelas não estão sendo criadas na base de dados.

Alguém saberia informar o que pode estar causando o erro?

Mensagem de erro:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: Ative o modo DEBUG no web.config para ter mais detalhes do erro. Veja se nao faltou rodar Migrations na base de producao. E verifique se, localmente, apos vc ter feito modificacoes no *login* se vc nao apagou todo o banco para que ele fosse recriado. As vezes eh isso que ele esta tentando fazer no Azure e nao esta conseguindo.

Comment: Eu baixei novamente o arquivo de Publish do Azure e funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Por gentileza, coloque isso como resposta à sua pergunta. Assim outros irão poder ser ajudados se tiverem o mesmo problema.

Comment: Provavelmente o problema esta na sua string de conexao.